# Can I enroll in a 2nd University after deferring admission from 1st University?

Tags: graduate-admissions, deferral

I have been accepted to my dream MS program in a top ranked US university. But I could not get the visa. From where I am, there is a problem getting visa if you do not have University funding.

Since, I couldn't get the visa, I am deferring this admission to the Fall 2019 (they do not accept Spring deferrals). Since it is such a long time away, and I have already waited a year, I want to apply to a funded program for the Spring 2019 semester and continue there till next Fall and then transfer to the first University from Fall 2019. But will enrolling in another program during my deferral make my deferral void?

Comment: I will guess that only the institution can make that determination. You can ask, of course. But it is possible that your visa will have problems in the future also. So it might be best to make sure you keep other options open.

Comment: Note that you will also likely burn a bridge with the 2nd university - if they knew you intended to use them as a temporary stop on the way to the 1st university they would never admit you in the first place (particularly with funding). As for the concerns of the 1st university, what does the deferral agreement say?

Comment: I still haven't deferred my admission, so I don't really know what my deferral agreement says. I will ask for my admission to be deferred after I take another visa interview. I am just pondering about the options open to me. Thanks